# How to increase Socket's transfer speed in c#

Tags: c#, performance, sockets, iis

I am developing a program using c# like thrift, And now I need a server like IIS can faster send data between client and server. this is done, but I found a problem: when server send/receive data from client. It is much slower than IIS.

My test case is both my program and IIS return the request client a blank page(content length is zero), just to testing and compare the concurrency level between them.

What I found is that: my program's transfer speed at most can be up to 600KB-1.1MB/s, however, IIS can up to 1.1MB-1.8MB/s

my question is:
Is socket in C# is intend slower than native socket, or something I can do to speed my socket's transfer speed up?

Main code is listed below:

```
/// <summary>
///     Http Service context
/// </summary>
public class HttpServerContext : ServerContext
{

    private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 16384;
    private static readonly byte[] HEADER_CACHE_CONTROL = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetBytes("Cache-Control:");
    private static readonly byte[] HEADER_CONNECTION_CLOSE = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetBytes("Connection:Close\r\n");
    private static readonly byte[] HEADER_CONNECTION_KEEP_ALIVE = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetBytes("Connection:keep-alive\r\n");
    private static readonly byte[] HEADER_CONTENT_ENCODING = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetBytes("Content-Encoding:");
    private static readonly byte[] HEADER_CONTENT_ENCODING_DEFLATE = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetBytes("Content-Encoding:deflate\r\n");
    private static readonly byte[] HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE_HTML = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetBytes("Content-Type:text/html\r\n");
    private static readonly byte[] HEADER_CONTENT_ENCODING_LENGTH = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetBytes("Content-Length:");
    private static readonly byte[] HEADER_CONTENT_ENCODING_LENGTH_0 = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetBytes("Content-Length:0\r\n");
    private static readonly byte[] HEADER_LAST_MODIFIED = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetBytes("Last-Modified:");
    private static readonly byte[] HEADER_EXPIRES = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetBytes("Expires:");
    private static readonly byte[] HEADER_ETAG = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetBytes("ETag:");
    private static readonly byte[] STATUS_OK = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetBytes("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
    private static readonly byte[] STATUS_ERROR = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetBytes("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Service Error\r\n");
    private static readonly byte[] STATUS_NOT_MODIFIED = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetBytes("HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified\r\n");
    private static readonly byte[] HEADER_SERVER = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetBytes("Server:Aria\r\n");
    private static readonly byte[] HEADER_END = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetBytes("\r\n");
    private readonly SocketAsyncEventArgs m_args;
    private readonly HttpServer m_server;
    private readonly byte[] m_buffer;
    private string m_ifModifiedSince;
    private int m_length;
    private int m_offset;
    private int m_timeout;
    private readonly LinkedList<byte[]> m_output = new LinkedList<byte[]>();
    private string m_queryString;
    private string m_requestEtag;
    private bool m_shutdown;
    private Socket m_socket;
    private string m_ticket;
    private string m_url;
    private static string m_sample;

    internal HttpServerContext(HttpServer server)
        : base(server)
    {
        this.m_server = server;
        this.m_args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        m_buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        this.m_args.SetBuffer(m_buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        this.m_args.Completed += Args_Completed;
    }

    private void Args_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
        {
            m_server.ReportError(e.SocketError);
            this.Close();
            return;
        }
        if (m_socket == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        switch (e.LastOperation)
        {
            case SocketAsyncOperation.Receive:
                this.ProcessReceive();
                break;
            case SocketAsyncOperation.Send:
                ProcessSend();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void ProcessSend()
    {
        int rest;
        LOOPSTART:
        int offset = 0;
        while (m_output.Count > 0)
        {
            LinkedListNode<byte[]> node = m_output.First;
            byte[] buffer = node.Value;
            CHUNK_START:
            rest = buffer.Length - m_offset;
            if (rest > BUFFER_SIZE)
            {
                Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, m_offset, m_buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                m_offset += BUFFER_SIZE;

                Log.Debug.Write("Send a chunk:" + m_socket.RemoteEndPoint + "\r\n" + FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetString(m_buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE));

                if (!m_socket.SendAsync(this.m_args))
                {
                    goto CHUNK_START;
                }
            }
            else if (rest == BUFFER_SIZE)
            {
                Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, m_offset, m_buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                m_offset = 0;
                m_output.Remove(node);

                Log.Debug.Write("Send final chunk of block:" + m_socket.RemoteEndPoint + "\r\n" + FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetString(m_buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE));

                if (!m_socket.SendAsync(this.m_args))
                {
                    goto LOOPSTART;
                }
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, m_offset, m_buffer, offset, rest);
                offset += rest;
                m_offset = 0;
                m_output.Remove(node);
            }
        }
        if (offset > 0)
        {

            Log.Debug.Write("Send final data of request:" + m_socket.RemoteEndPoint + "\r\n" + FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetString(m_buffer, 0, offset));

            m_args.SetBuffer(0, offset);
            if (m_socket.SendAsync(this.m_args)) 
            {
                return;
            }

            Log.Debug.Write("Done by sync:" + m_socket.RemoteEndPoint + "," + m_args.BytesTransferred);

        }
        m_args.SetBuffer(0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        if (m_socket == null)
        {
            m_server.ReportError("Socket closed");
            this.Close();
        }
        else if (m_shutdown)
        {
            m_server.ReportError("Shutdown");
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {

            Log.Debug.Write("Next request/response workflow:" + m_socket.RemoteEndPoint);

            this.NextWorkflow();
        }
    }

    private void ProcessReceive()
    {

        int bytes = m_args.BytesTransferred;
        if (bytes == 0) 
        {
            m_timeout++;
            if (m_timeout < 100)
            {
                if (!m_socket.ReceiveAsync(this.m_args))
                {
                    Args_Completed(null, m_args);
                }
                return;
            }
            m_server.ReportError("Zero data");
            this.Close();
            return;
        }
        m_timeout = 0;
        if (bytes == BUFFER_SIZE) 
        {
            m_server.ReportError("Request too large");
            this.Close();
            return;
        }
        if (m_sample == null)
        {
            m_sample = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetString(m_buffer, 0, bytes);
            Console.WriteLine(m_sample);
        }
        int offset = 0;
        int cursor = 0;
        int count;
        string header = null;
        while (cursor < bytes)
        {
            byte c = m_buffer[cursor];
            switch (c)
            {
                case 0x0D: //\r
                    count = cursor - offset;
                    if (count == 0)
                    {
                        goto END;
                    }
                    if (!ProcessRequest(offset, count, ref header))
                    {
                        m_server.ReportError("Parse request error");
                        this.Close();
                        return;
                    }
                    cursor++;
                    MoveForwardIf(ref cursor, '\n', bytes);
                    offset = cursor;
                    continue;
                case 0x0A: //\n
                    count = cursor - offset;
                    if (count == 0)
                    {
                        goto END;
                    }
                    if (!ProcessRequest(offset, count, ref header))
                    {
                        m_server.ReportError("Parse request error");
                        this.Close();
                        return;
                    }
                    offset = cursor + 1;
                    break;

                case 0x3A:
                    if (header == null)
                    {
                        header = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetString(m_buffer, offset, cursor - offset);
                        cursor++;
                        MoveForwardIf(ref cursor, ' ', bytes);
                        offset = cursor;
                        continue;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            cursor++;
        }
        END:
        if (m_url != null)
        {
            if (m_socket != null)
            {
                this.ProcessExecute();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            m_server.ReportError("Parse url error");
            this.Close();
        }


    }

    private void MoveForwardIf(ref int cursor, char ch, int len)
    {
        while (cursor < len)
        {
            if (m_buffer[cursor] == ch)
            {
                cursor++;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private bool ProcessRequest(int offset, int count, ref string header)
    {
        try
        {
            if (m_url == null)
            {
                #region 分析QueryString 和 Url

                if (count < 6)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                int index1 = offset + 4;
                if (m_buffer[index1] != '/')
                {
                    return false; //POST is not supported yet
                }
                int index2 = -1;
                int index3 = -1;
                for (int i = offset + count - 1; i != offset; i--)
                {
                    byte c = m_buffer[i];
                    if (c == ' ' && index3 != -1)
                    {
                        index3 = i;
                    }
                    if (c == '?')
                    {
                        index2 = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (index2 == -1)
                {
                    m_queryString = string.Empty;
                    if (index3 == -1)
                    {
                        m_url = string.Empty;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        m_url = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetString(m_buffer, index1 + 1, index3 - index1 - 1);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    m_url = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetString(m_buffer, index1 + 1, index2 - index1 - 1);
                    m_queryString = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetString(m_buffer, index2 + 1, index3 - index2 - 1);
                }

                #endregion

                return true;
            }
            else if (header == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            switch (header.ToLower())
            {
                case "if-match":
                case "if-none-match":
                    m_requestEtag = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetString(m_buffer, offset, count);
                    break;
                case "if-unmodified-since":
                case "if-modified-since":
                    m_ifModifiedSince = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetString(m_buffer, offset, count);
                    break;
                case "connection":
                    string keepAlive = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetString(m_buffer, offset, count);
                    m_server.ReportError("KeepAlive:" + keepAlive);
                    break;
                case "ticket":
                    m_ticket = FrameworkConfig.Encoding.GetString(m_buffer, offset, count);
                    break;
            }
            header = null;
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Critical.WriteError(e);
            return false;
        }
    }


    private void ProcessExecute()
    {
        try
        {
            m_output.AddLast(STATUS_OK);
            m_output.AddLast(HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE_HTML);
            m_output.AddLast(HEADER_CONNECTION_KEEP_ALIVE);
            m_output.AddLast(HEADER_CONTENT_ENCODING_DEFLATE);
            m_output.AddLast(HEADER_CONTENT_ENCODING_LENGTH_0);
            m_output.AddLast(HEADER_SERVER);
            m_output.AddLast(HEADER_END);

            //TODO Execute the real service....
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Critical.WriteError(e);
            m_server.ReportError("Execute error");
            m_output.Clear();
            m_length = 0;
            m_output.AddLast(STATUS_ERROR);
            m_output.AddLast(HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE_HTML);
            m_output.AddLast(HEADER_CONNECTION_CLOSE);
            m_output.AddLast(HEADER_CONTENT_ENCODING_DEFLATE);
            m_output.AddLast(HEADER_CONTENT_ENCODING_LENGTH_0);
            m_output.AddLast(HEADER_SERVER);
            m_output.AddLast(HEADER_END);
            m_shutdown = true;
        }
        this.ProcessSend();
    }

    internal void Start(Socket socket)//Here is the main workflow portal, the server accept a socket and send to this method to process request
    {
        this.m_socket = socket;
        this.m_args.AcceptSocket = socket;
        m_shutdown = false;
        this.NextWorkflow();
    }

    private void NextWorkflow()
    {
        m_url = null;
        m_ticket = null;
        m_ifModifiedSince = null;
        m_queryString = null;
        m_requestEtag = null;
        m_output.Clear();

        Log.Debug.Write("Receive next request:" + m_socket.RemoteEndPoint);

        this.m_output.Clear();
        if (!m_socket.ReceiveAsync(this.m_args))
        {
            Args_Completed(null, m_args);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code. Have you profiled the app yet? What's taking most time?

Comment: I posted my code there. the main workflow is a server accept socket connection, then peak a http server context from pool, and ask context to finish the work.

Comment: I'm not going to read through all of that.; How many clients do you expect the service to serve? Maybe you should just toss out all the async code complexity and go synchronous. This mess is hard to comprehend. Async IO does not make your network faster. It is meant as a way to scale to hundreds of clients. I assume you don't have that.

Comment: I have profited yet, the method Args_Complete takes 68% of cpu, inside it, Socket's SendAsync takes 32.7%

Comment: In fact my application may be thousands of client. But I think you provided me a good choice...I may test it again.

Comment: 1000s of clients are a good case for async. Consider using async/await which is possible even with .NET 4 and VS12.

Comment: I think I found the reason, with your advise, I run a benchmark, when each thread transfer a small block data each time, the speed is down, but if you transfer large data, the speed is up.